# "Решение" вместо "Ответ"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Хотелось бы внести предложение к рассмотрению.

Очень часто новички пытаются общаться, добавлять какие-то уточнения к своим вопросам и замечания к другим ответам или даже комментариям с помощью ответа на вопрос. Поведение, в принципе, для людей, которые привыкли к формату форума и мало знакомы с принципами Q&A, вполне объяснимое. Человек видит какую-то информацию, к которой ему есть что добавить и видит "Отправить ваш ответ" - вот он и отвечает на ответ. Все это конечно правится, тревогается, вразумляется и исправляется в большинстве случаев, но я бы хотел предложить переименовать все, что связано с ответами в "решение".

То есть: "Ваше решение", "отправить ваше решение", "Решение полезно" и тд. Мне думается, что такая формулировка более полно отображает суть происходящего, более правильная по значению процесса и не допускает двойного толкования, как "Ответ".

Да, устоявшееся название Q&A - вопрос и ответ, но пусть будет Q&S - вопрос и решение.

Хотелось бы знать, кто что думает, возможно ли вообще и нужно ли кому-то еще.

Comment: Если суть такого изменения только в защите от размещения сообщений в ненужных местах новичками, то мне кажется это ровным счетом ничего не изменит.