# Переформулировать фразу "ваш ответ" чтобы не писали в поле новый вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Очень часто новички, которые не сталкивались с форматом SO думают, что поле "Ответ" -- это такая форма для reply в тему, а не для answer/solution и пишут туда свой вопрос или какой-то комментарий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть стоит назвать это поле как-то иначе, чем "ваш ответ", чтобы снизить число подобного рода ошибок?

Comment: Они пишут ответом, т.к. комментарии им ещё не доступны.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Понятно, что такие тоже есть. Однако возможно, что есть и вполне законопослушные участники, которые сейчас пишут, т.к. не особо понятно, а так остановятся и не будут писать.

Comment: я уже пытался что то [такое предложить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4831/177345), но не встретил понимания :(

Comment: @pavlofff да, "Ваше решение" подошло бы идеально.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса ["Решение" вместо "Ответ"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4831/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: А есть статистика? Ну и моё мнение по сути осталось [прежним](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4831/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82#comment17447_4831).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Статистику не собирал, субъективно примерно так ощущается: в сутки не менее 3-4 человек пишет в ответ комментарии. PS А мнение неплохо бы перенести в поле "Ваш ответ" ;-)

Comment: Возможно, оно (мнение) там и писалось. Но из-за недостаточной длины автоматически перекочевало в поле комментария. Т.е. сама система противится тому, чтобы комментарий был ответом :)

Comment: То что предлагает @pavlofff может быть решением. Так как в английском языке *Answer* означает *ответ на вопрос*, а для просто ответа в видет ответа на сообщение используется *Reply*. Для русского языка верным был бы выбор использовать *Решение*.

Comment: Эта проблема была бы значительно меньше, если бы у новичков была возможность писать комментарии. Нередки случаи, когда у человека есть полезная информация для TC, но ее слишком мало для ответа. Логично, что ее пишут в комментарий. Но новичков почему-то лишили такой возможности.

Comment: Не знаю как тут устроена система перевода, но прямая замена "ваш ответ" => "ваше решение" проблему не исправит, возможно лучше будет смотреться и пониматься более полный перевод "ваш ответ на вопрос", если движок такое позволит. Да многословно, но более однозначно, русский язык вообще многословен, ну не считая не нормативного варианта разумеется =) По поводу замечания о комментариях - спорно, с одной стороны кажется полезным, с другой - количество бесполезных/вредных комментариев от случайно зашедших может значительно увеличиться.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд это лучший вариант, чем ответ.
Слово решение лучше описывает, что это должно быть. Хотя вопрос и ответ лучше сочетаются.

Hовички могут подумать , что решение это значит, что тут можно предлагать задачи, которые не пытались решать. Так что предлагаю сделать подсказку что такое ответ (или решение).

Comment: Кстати да, когда в вопросе копипастят задания, то в решение начнут постить свои простыни неправильных решений